# CMAKE calling system commands

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project(XXXXPack_Installation)


add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT 
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/XXXXPack.32.0/config.status"
   DEPENDS unZip
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
   ARGS -E chdir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/XXXXPack.32.0 ./configure
   COMMENT "Configuring  using Autotools"
   )  

add_custom_command(
   OUTPUT 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/XXXXInstallation_genfile 
   DEPENDS 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/XXXXPack.32.0/config.status
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
   ARGS -E chdir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/XXXXPack.32.0 make
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
   ARGS -E chdir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/XXXXPack.32.0 make install
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
   ARGS -E chdir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/XXXXPack.32.0 make samples
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
   ARGS -E chdir ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/XXXXPack.32.0 make config
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo Running: ldconfig
   COMMAND 
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/XXXXInstallation_genfile
   COMMENT "Compiling & Installing XXXX"
   )                     


add_custom_target(makedlu ALL
    DEPENDS 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/XXXXPack.32.0/config.status 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/XXXXInstallation_genfile
    COMMAND 
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo XXXX for custom target generated
    WORKING_DIRECTORY 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    VERBATIM
)
```

Hi,

The above cmake compiles and installs a package, i am unable to do some post bulid steps like ldconfig,adduser, usermod, chown,chmod etc with the help of above commands.I i am trying to call ldconfig like this

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E ldconfig
```

it throws error. How can the above steps like ldconfig,adduser, usermod, chown,chmod can be accomplished using cmake. I tried adding external shell script and executing that but its also not working, cmake executes without any error but commands in shell script didn't bring any effect.

Comment: Just `COMMAND ldconfig`

Comment: That worked like a charm :) Thank you